Excel application automation testing strategies
I have been newly assigned on a project which has Excel applications. Has anyone worked on one before? Have you implemented any automation strategies for the same? I have been researching the possibilities of Selenium and APache poi to make this work . But just wondering if there is any other alternative open source frameworks available or is better to go with Selenium itself? Let me know if you have similar experience and how you tackled it.

Selenium is actually not an alternative, because it is meant for Web Browsers (unless we are talking about Excel online in the browser).
Apache POI in Java is one of the most stable and well supported.
Some other alternatives are:
1 - Powershell
# Create an Excel application instance
$excelApp = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excelApp.Visible = $false

# Open an Excel workbook
$workbook = $excelApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\path\to\your\file.xlsx")

# Select a worksheet
$worksheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)

# Read a specific cell value
$cellValue = $worksheet.Cells.Item(1, 1).Value2

# Perform a test on the cell value (example)
if ($cellValue -eq "Expected Value") {
    Write-Host "Test Passed"
} else {
    Write-Host "Test Failed"
}

# Clean up
$workbook.Close($false)
$excelApp.Quit()

2 - Python
With openpyxl
import openpyxl

# Load the Excel workbook
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook("path/to/your/file.xlsx")

# Select a worksheet
worksheet = workbook["Sheet1"]

# Read a specific cell value
cell_value = worksheet["A1"].value

# Perform a test on the cell value (example)
if cell_value == "Expected Value":
    print("Test Passed")
else:
    print("Test Failed")

# Save and close the workbook (if needed)
workbook.save("path/to/your/file.xlsx")

Or Pandas
import pandas as pd

# Load the Excel file into a DataFrame
data = pd.read_excel("path/to/your/file.xlsx", sheet_name="Sheet1")

# Check a specific value
cell_value = data.iloc[0, 0]  # First row, first column

# Perform a test on the value (example)
if cell_value == "Expected Value":
    print("Test Passed")
else:
    print("Test Failed")

3 - VBA
Sub TestAutomationExample()
    ' Get the first worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

    ' Get the value in cell A1
    Dim cellValue As String
    cellValue = ws.Range("A1").Value

    ' Expected value to check
    Dim expectedValue As String
    expectedValue = "Expected Value"

    ' Test if the cell value matches the expected value
    If cellValue = expectedValue Then
        ' Test passed, display a message box
        MsgBox "Test Passed!", vbInformation
    Else
        ' Test failed, display a different message box
        MsgBox "Test Failed!", vbCritical
    End If
End Sub

